# Plotting legend only in tmap

Tags: r, gis, tmap

I have a crowded map I've generated using the `tmap` library, I've turned the legend off with the argument `legend.show = FALSE` in the `tm_layout()` function.

What I want to know is the following: is there a way to generate a legend for this map on its own? So that it could be a stand alone image?

(I'm sorry the code won't give you a map)

```
tm_borders()+
tm_shape(parks)+
  tm_polygons()+
tm_shape(houses)+
  tm_polygons()+
tm_shape(grid)+
    tm_polygons(col="n", style ="cont", palette="plasma",alpha = 0.5)+
tm_layout(legend.show=FALSE)
```

**EDIT:**
Yes. It's in the help file and it's this:
argument `legend.only = TRUE` in the `tm_layout()` function.

```
  tm_borders()+
    tm_shape(parks)+
      tm_polygons()+
    tm_shape(houses)+
      tm_polygons()+
    tm_shape(grid)+
        tm_polygons(col="n", style ="cont", palette="plasma",alpha = 0.5)+
    tm_layout(legend.only= T)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: Yes. It's in the help file and it's this: legend.only

```
tm_borders()+
    tm_shape(parks)+
      tm_polygons()+
    tm_shape(houses)+
      tm_polygons()+
    tm_shape(grid)+
        tm_polygons(col="n", style ="cont", palette="plasma",alpha = 0.5)+
    tm_layout(legend.only= T)
```